# Разбить побитово 3 байта и получить значения

Tags: java

Задача: Целое без знака, 3 байта

1. 9...0 - Скорость, в дм/с
2. 18...10 - Направление, в градусах
3. 22...19 - Количество спутников (при захвате более 15 спутников
       передается 15)
4. 23 - Не используется. Равен 0.

   short speedByte = buf.getShort();//2
       int speed = (speedByte & 0x3FF);

   ```
   byte b = buf.get();//1
   float angle = (speedByte >> 10) + ((b & 0x03) << 7);

   int count_satellites = b  >> 2;
   ```

Считает неправильно, где я ошибаюсь? Помогите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    byte byteSpeed = buf.get();//1
    byte byteAngle = buf.get();//1
    byte byteSatellites = buf.get();//1

    byte[] test = new byte[]{(byte) 0, byteSatellites, byteAngle, byteSpeed};

    ByteBuffer allocate = ByteBuffer.wrap(test);
    int anInt = allocate.getInt();

    int speed = (anInt & 0x3FF);
    float angle = (anInt & 0x7FC00) >> 10;
    int count_satellites = (anInt & 0x780000) >> 19;
```

С помощью прогерского калькулятора разобрался. ) Всем спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
int source = 43214234123412;
int speed = source & 0x000003FF
int direction = (source >> 10) & 0x000003FF;
int amount = (source >> 19) & 0x0000000F;
```

Comment: Скобки необязательны, приоритет сдвига выше, чем у конъюнкции.

Comment: Скобки для наглядности.